# Getting frequencies in Apriori algorithm in Weka

Tags: algorithm, associations, weka, data-mining, apriori

I'm trying to apply the Apriori algorithm in [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/).
Wikipedia has a simple example for that ([Apriori algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apriori_algorithm#Example_1)):

```
alpha beta epsilon
alpha beta theta
alpha beta epsilon
alpha beta theta
```

The following association rules can be determined from this table:

- 100% of sets with `alpha` also contain `beta`
- 50% of sets with `alpha`, beta also have `epsilon`
- 50% of sets with `alpha`, beta also have `theta`

I converted this entries into a CSV and added another attribute row, so that I finally had this file:

```
prod1,prod2,prod3
alpha,beta,epsilon
alpha,beta,theta
alpha,beta,epsilon
alpha,beta,theta
```

I loaded it into Weka and clicked the tab "Associate", the algorithm "Apriori" is selected per default.

As a result I get the following:

```
 1. prod2=beta 4 ==> prod1=alpha 4    conf:(1)
 2. prod1=alpha 4 ==> prod2=beta 4    conf:(1)
 3. prod3=epsilon 2 ==> prod1=alpha 2    conf:(1)
 4. prod3=theta 2 ==> prod1=alpha 2    conf:(1)
 5. prod3=epsilon 2 ==> prod2=beta 2    conf:(1)
 6. prod3=theta 2 ==> prod2=beta 2    conf:(1)
 7. prod2=beta prod3=epsilon 2 ==> prod1=alpha 2    conf:(1)
 8. prod1=alpha prod3=epsilon 2 ==> prod2=beta 2    conf:(1)
 9. prod3=epsilon 2 ==> prod1=alpha prod2=beta 2    conf:(1)
10. prod2=beta prod3=theta 2 ==> prod1=alpha 2    conf:(1)
```

But I also want the frequencies as in the example from Wikipedia (see above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confidence that Weka gives you (`conf:(1)`) is exactly the "frequencies" that you want.

As you can see, your rule "50% of sets with alpha, beta also have epsilon" is not in the output of Weka. This is because Weka lists rules sorted by confidence in decreasing order. So, to list your 50% rule, you need to increase the number of outputs from Weka.

This can be done by increasing "numRules" (whose default value is 10, see the screenshot below). For your particular example you will also need to decrees "minMetric" from 0.9 to 0.5 (or lower).

[image: Weka GUI Apriori parameters]